# generate emacs org agenda view from a few org files

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using Emacs org and enjoy it. I know org agenda and try it,  but do not keep using it. Because I always have a lot of things to do, a few projects, home and personal things.All these are recorded in a few org files.

How can I generate one agenda view from these a few org files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Customise the `org-agenda-files` variable.

You can do this interactively by visiting your Org files and add them to the agenda files by pressing `C-c [`. The agenda files may be stored in a section like the following in your init file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-agenda-files (quote ("~/org/gtd.org"))))
```

Some advice: this is basic Org functionality. I suggest working through one of the good tutorials out there to learn the basic Org commands and customisation options, for example http://orgmode.org/guide/Agenda-files.html#Agenda-files.